# Nested custom error pages in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5, custom-error-pages

. .

I'm trying to set up IIS 7 to use custom error pages, but I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to get around.  I've looked nearly everywhere for an answer to this, and have come up empty.

Here's the deal: I open IIS, go into Error Pages (note: this is a classic ASP environment), and open Edit Feature Settings.  I set my path type to Execute URL and set my path (for example purposes, let's say it's "/errors/SomeError.asp").  I also set it to "Custom Error Pages."

For the most part, it seems to be okay, but here's where I run into trouble.

I'm sure you've all seen the errors where your page partially loads, and the error appears in the middle of the page.  (For example, you'll see your page template, and somewhere in the middle, you'll see your "Error 500 . . . " blah blah blah.)

The error page I created (the "/errors/SomeError.asp" I mention above) is a full page, complete with template and everything.

When an error occurs mid-page, it does not redirect to my custom error page.  Instead, the page is "nested" -- that is, the full page appears right in the middle of the problem page -- so it looks like a full page within a full page.

I want it to go to the error page, not have the error page nested within the page.

How do I get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered my own question.

Instead of setting path type to "Execute URL," I set it to "Redirect."  Problem solved.